# filtering an object array on a feild that is an array , by using an array

Tags: javascript, filter

Lets say I have the two following arrays.
The goal here is to filter "foods" array with the values of "tagsValues".
I want to return a new array of foods, where foods.tags include one or several items from tagsValues.

```
const tagsValues = ['gluten-free', 'carb-free', 'flavor-free'];
const foods = [
  { name: 'pasta', tags: ['delicious', 'has carbs']}, 
  { name: 'gluten-free-pizza', tags: ['gluten-free']}, 
  { name: 'soda', tags: ['delicious', 'has sugars']}, 
  { name: 'pizza', tags: ['delicious', 'best meal of the year','carb-free']},
  { name: 'rice cakes', tags: ['flavor-free','carb-free']}
]
```

In this example , I need to get the following result :

```
result = [ 
  { name: 'gluten-free-pizza', tags: ['gluten-free']}, 
  { name: 'pizza', tags: ['delicious', 'best meal of the year','carb-free']},
  { name: 'rice cakes', tags: ['flavor-free','carb-free']}
]
```

So far I have tried the following. It seems to work only if there is only one value in foods.tags and that's a problem since most of the time foods.tags will have several items.

```
result= foods.filter(obj => { 
return (
[...obj.tags].some(item => tagsValues.includes(item))
)})
```

Comment: `some` short-circuits when it finds a match, so your code works, and you're getting the output you want (although you're making an necessary step of creating a copy of the tags array).

Comment: whats going wrong